# ERROR in : Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive CdkObserveContent in node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/typings/index.d.ts

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, angular5, ng-build

I am getting an error as below on my Angular 5 application. I am using `Angular CLI` and running from `VSCode`.

> ERROR in : Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive
>   CdkObserveContent in
>   node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/typings/index.d.ts.

The error is getting throws only when I execute `ng build --prod`. The commands `ng serve` and `ng build` wors fine.

[image]

Any idea, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let me answer my own question. This is really strange. I have changed the value of `rootDir` on my `tsconfig.json` file to `.`, that solved the issue here. This [post](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8070) really helped me to do so. I am not sure what is the relation `ng build --prod` has with this `rootDir`. Now all the commands are working fine.

**Previous `tsconfig.json`**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": "bin",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**New `tsconfig.json`**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": "bin",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: After run application I got error :ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(h)[n -> n]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[n -> n]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for n!

Comment: @sameer: run `ng build --prod --optimization=false` and find out what is causing the error